# Matrix Transpose Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $A$ be a $3×3$ matrix such that $A^TA = I$. Show that the cosine of the angle between any two vectors $u$ and $v$ is always equal to the cosine of the
angles between the vectors $uA^T$ and $vA^T$.

I know that the cosine of the angle between two vectors can be given by $u \cdot v/|u||v|$ and that $u \cdot v = uA \cdot vA$, but I don't know that to prove that it also works for $A^T$.

Comment: There is a key property of the matrix transpose when it is used in an inner product. Find it and add it to your question.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Sorry, Louis, that's not the fact that you want to use here. Do you have a text book, or lecture notes? Look for an equation with something like $\langle A^Tx,y\rangle $ in it. And I guess you also need to find a formula for the cosine of the angle between two vectors. Like saulspatz says, you need to add more to your question.

Comment: BTW, if you want to write a dot product in LaTeX, use `$u \cdot v$` for $u \cdot v$.

Comment: Also, I used the notation $\langle A^Tx,y\rangle$ for a dot product, which isn't what you're using. With your notation you should be looking for a formula that contains $(A^Tx) \cdot y$, or something similar.

Comment: From the first statement, I know that A is invertible. Then from the inner products of matrices, $u \cdot v = Au \cdot Av$. Since the dot products are the same, the cosine of the angle will be the same. Is this correct?

Comment: Well, $u \cdot v = Au \cdot Av$ is (kind of like) what you'd like to show -- really it's $u \cdot v = (uA^T) \cdot (vA^T)$ that would do it. Also, "dot product of matrices" isn't really a thing that exists, not for $3\times3$ matrices. Your instructor might use it, but it really blurs the lines between vectors and matrices. Do you know how to rewrite the dot product of two $n \times 1$ vectors using matrix multiplication?

Comment: Yes I have seen that. The problem is that this inner products is not something that I have learned yet, but I am getting questions which seem to be only solvable using it, hence my confusion on the knowledge.

Comment: Well, if we're trying to answer questions about the inner product without having learned about it yet, I'm kind of at a dead end. Sorry about that. Maybe someone else can crack this coming from a different angle. Good luck.